# modify .form-group attributes in django forms using cripsy

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I noticed there is a margin in the .form-group class when uding django crispy forms. This creates an extra margin that I want to remove, how can I change that?

When I inspect the element I find out that the cripsy field I am using is rendered in the browser like this:

```
<div id="div_id_assurance" class="form-group">
```

And this form-group class has these attributes:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

I want to get rid of this margin-bottom, can I do it using `self.fields['assurance'].widget.attrs.update({'SOMETHING' : 'SOMETHING'})`?

Comment: Can I do this? self.fields['assurance'].widget.attrs.update({'style' : 'margin-bottom: 0rem;'}) ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions:

I added this

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

to a css file and linked it in the html using the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'dashboard/main.css' %}">`